# How to change the color of the iOS autocorrect suggestion?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextview

After much searching here and on the web and in developer forums, I can't believe that nobody seems to have even asked this question before.

The iOS autocorrect suggestions always popup with a blue font on a white background, regardless of the colors of your UITextField or UITextView or anything else. This looks pretty bad sometimes, e.g. on a dark background. It seems bizarre that it would adopt the font of the text you're editing, but have no way to change the default colors.

And yet in the built-in iOS Notes app, the autocorrect suggestions appear beautifully with a yellow background and red font.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 3):

The `UITextInput` protocol defines a method `- (NSDictionary *)textStylingAtPosition:(UITextPosition *)position inDirection:(UITextStorageDirection)direction` which the docs claim can be used to style correction rectangles. I gather this would be communicated through a UITextPosition subclass that indicates styling information is being requested, but I'm not sure on the details of that. Something to look more into for sure!

EDIT:

I just implemented a UITextField and a UITextView subclass and overrode the below method. The method was never called :( Sorry to answer with false hope!

EDIT 2: found a blog post explaining why it was never called: http://bjhomer.blogspot.com/2011/11/detecting-backspace-in-uitextfield.html

Comment: +1 for the pointer, perhaps I can use that by writing a complete replacement for UITextField instead of subclassing. It might be more work than is justified though, so I'm going to hold off for now. It's strange that there doesn't seem to be a simpler way to just change the color :(

Comment: @sup Check out the second edit I just made. May put you further down the right path if you can determine that `UIFieldEditor` is responsible for any of this.

Comment: did the OP ever find the answer to this? check out my bounty on a similar (actually maybe duplicate question) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684167/autocorrect-issue-with-a-colored-uitextview)