# Autocorrect issue with a colored UITextview

Tags: ios, uitextview, autocorrect

I'm using in my app a textview with blue colored background.

When autocorrect is enabled, whenever it corrects a word a white box forms around the word and the text's color changes also.

Any ideas on how to stop this effect?

Comment: I have the same question and I couldn't find an answer... anyone? I am offering a bounty for an answer to this (that would not be rejected from app store)

Comment: COME ON! not even a comment? does no one else ever use autocorrect with a colored UITextView? is it just me (and OP) that have this problem? At least post a comment and say "i'm having the same issue and I think..."

Comment: Sorry. I did some searching around and could find no helpful information.

Comment: Unanswered similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172006/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-ios-autocorrect-suggestion

Comment: @JSuar thanks for the link. I've already seen it before. Unfortunately, no answers yet...

Comment: did anyone find a fix to this? I'm facing this with another app I'm making, and it's still there, even in iOS 7 beta... I can't say more (NDA)...

Answer (score 4):

Nope, I think you can't change the color of the overlay or the textcolor out of the box..

This is a hard one, if you put a breakpoint in `- (void) layoutSubviews {..}` of your view you'll see UIKit has drawn a 'UITextSelectionView' above the text...

I tried to subclass UITextView to see if its layoutSubviews get's fired and it seems it does!

So I tried to remove the overlay:

```
- (void) layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
        if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITextSelectionView"]) {
            DLog(@"Subview %@", [subview debugDescription]);
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And it worked.. but that results in missing the cursor, and disabling any selection :(

I think you'll have to disable autocorrect..

**I'll re-start the bounty if someone finds a real answer!**

Comment: Autocorrect is a must in my app, I can't disable it. Will try your code and hope I can figure something out. thanks for the effort.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so, good luck with it! Let me know if you found something!

Comment: :( it seems no answer is found. I'll award you the bounty since it would be a shame to let it go to waste.

Comment: Too bad :( If anyone finds a real answer I'll re-start the bounty!

Answer (score 0):

This may have other side effects I am currently investigating what else calls this, but overriding firstRect(for range) in UITextView and returning CGrect.Zero removes the highlight.

```
override public func firstRect(for range: UITextRange) -> CGRect {
     return CGRect.zero;
}
```