# Swift change background color of the auto correction toolbar

Tags: ios, swift, autocomplete, keyboard, uitoolbar

how can I change the background color of the auto complete toolbar from gray to blue?

Thx for your help.

[image]

Comment: Have you seen any app do that? I would not be surprised if that is simply not possible.

Comment: It would be great when it was possible. I would like to have all the toolbars in my app to have the same UIToolBar background color. It would be great for the overall look and feel of the app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the color of the iOS autocorrect suggestion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172006/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-ios-autocorrect-suggestion)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to customize the **System Keyboard** . You only can change the keyboard appearance as `.Dark` , `.Light` , `.Alert` and `.Default` . But you can build your **Own Keyboard** using `UIInputViewController` .